# JQuery Validation With Multiple Sets Of Radio Buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a `form` that did submit 1 out of 8 `radio` buttons to a `php` `$_POST` super global array.  Therefore, I needed some validation.  I was kindly helped by being provided this code which works great:

```
$("#form").submit(function (event) {

            if(!$(":radio:checked").length) {

            alert("You must select at least one emotional state!");
            event.preventDefault();

            }
        });
```

However, I have now been asked to have 2 sets of 8 `radio` buttons in which the user selects 2 answers instead of the initial 1 answer.  I need the code to be able to determine that at least one `radio` button from each set of 8 buttons has been selected before the form is submitted.  At the moment the code checks to see if any `radio` buttons have been selected, then as soon as just 1 buttons is selected, the function is satisfied and transitions to the next page, which is not what I want.

EDIT

Buttons code:

```
<p><input type="radio" value="happy" name="perceived_emotion">Happy
<input type="radio" value="excited" name="perceived_emotion">Excited
<input type="radio" value="angry" name="perceived_emotion">Angry
<input type="radio" value="frustrated" name="perceived_emotion">Frustrated
<input type="radio" value="miserable" name="perceived_emotion">Miserable
<input type="radio" value="sad" name="perceived_emotion">Sad
<input type="radio" value="tired" name="perceived_emotion">Tired
<input type="radio" value="relaxed" name="perceived_emotion">Relaxed</p>

<p><input type="radio" value="happy" name="induced_emotion">Happy
<input type="radio" value="excited" name="induced_emotion">Excited
<input type="radio" value="angry" name="induced_emotion">Angry
<input type="radio" value="frustrated" name="induced_emotion">Frustrated
<input type="radio" value="miserable" name="induced_emotion">Miserable
<input type="radio" value="sad" name="induced_emotion">Sad
<input type="radio" value="tired" name="induced_emotion">Tired
<input type="radio" value="relaxed" name="induced_emotion">Relaxed</p>
```

Here is the `form` code:

```
<form id="form" action="audio_handler.php?id=1" method="POST">

                <div id="perceived_emotions">
                <?php include("includes/induced_emotion_buttons.php"); ?>       
                </div>

                <br />

                <div id="induced_emotions">
                <?php include("includes/perceived_emotion_buttons.php"); ?>
                </div>

                <p class="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>

            </form>
```

Comment: We need more code, like where is :radio:checked coming from?
Show the HTML and any other javascript/jquery you have on the page please :D

Comment: Just editing my post now.

Comment: First of all, you will need to convert the radio buttons to check boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use the `[name="value"]` selector in JQuery in conjunction with the `:checked` selector. So your new code would be:

```
if(!$('input[name="perceived_emotion"]:checked').length) {
  alert("You must select at least one perceived emotional state!");
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

if(!$('input[name="induced_emotion"]:checked').length) {
  alert("You must select at least one induced emotional state!");
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

All of that wrapped into the form event.

**EDIT:** Since you only want to display one dialog at once, just add `return false;` in each if statement.

Comment: Excellent :-)  Thanks, works a treat.  However, I may get the two individual dialogs to appear actually on the webpage as the alert box popping up twice is a tad annoying.  Mind you, I'm hoping the users' complete each question on each page, so no messages pop up at all!

Comment: I see - I thought after reading on the JQuery site that `return false` was equivalent to`event.preventDefault();`?  Thanks again, I'll try it in the morning as I've shut everything down now.