# Radio button selection issue when the back button is pressed in Chrome

Tags: html, forms

I have 16 `radio` buttons that are part of two questions for a survey ( 8 buttons per question).  When both questions have been answered, the `php` redirects to the next page which is identical, and so on and so forth.

When the back button is pressed in the browser, I expected both previous answers to still be `checked`.  In Chrome, one previous answer out of two always remains `checked`.  In Safari, both previous answers remain checked, which is what I expected.  Its not a huge problem, but it would be good if Chrome behaved the same way.  I've also made sure both caches were emptied, etc.

I posted a related question yesterday which shows how I am displaying and validating the `radio` buttons:

[JQuery Validation With Multiple Sets Of Radio Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114822/jquery-validation-with-multiple-sets-of-radio-buttons/27115256#27115256)

If this is not sufficient, I can post more code.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely what you need to do is track each question's answers using something like $_SESSION['answer_1'] = 1;

Then you need to make sure your browsers do not control the form's state by disabling autocomplete:

```
<form action="some_file.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

And then all you need to do is add this in your forms:

```
<Input type='radio' name='question1choice1' value= '1' <?=(($_SESSION['answer_1' == 1) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');?>Choice 1
<Input type='radio' name='question1choice2' value= '2' <?=(($_SESSION['answer_1' == 2) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');?>Choice 2
```

Comment: Thanks - I've added `autocomplete="off"` and now when the back button is pressed, no choices are active, which is better than having just one choice selected out of the two.  I'm just a little bit confused with the code within the input tags.  What is the shorthand `if` statement saying?  All answers do indeed get stored into the `$_SESSION` array like so: `$_SESSION['songs']['song01'] = array('question01' => $_POST['question01'], 'question02' => $_POST['question02']......`

Comment: The shorthand basically means: if ($_SESSION[xyz] == something) { do this } else { do that }; More info here (Ternary operator) : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php