# HTML radio button remains checked when page is requested again with the previous button

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, firefox, opera

#### Problem

When a page with a radio button form is requested again by clicking on the "previous page" button, the form is reloaded with the previously checked radio button "checked" again. Clearing or disabling Chrome cache doesn't make any difference. This behaviour is present in Chrome (Windows, Android), Chromium (Linux), Opera (Windows and Linux) and Firefox (Windows). MS Edge (Windows) and Firefox (Linux) doesn't show that behaviour and return on the test page with all  radio buttons unchecked.

In all browsers, when the page is refreshed (F5 ou ctrl-F5) all the radio buttons are unchecked though.

I am a little bit puzzled by this and I wonder what is the expected behaviour. If this is normal, what can I do to "uncheck" all buttons when returned to the page?

#### HTML page used to check this

```
<form action="radio_next_page.html" method="GET">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="foo">1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="foo">2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="foo">3

    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Add `autocomplete="off"` to the form. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27133091/5131623